# When does $E[f(X_i)]=E[f(X_j)], i\neq j$?

Tags: self-study, independence, iid

Suppose we have random variables $X_1, \dots, X_N$, with joint probability distribution $F_{X_1,\dots,X_N}$. Under what conditions does the following equality holds?

$$E[f(X_i)]=E[f(X_j)],\ \  i\neq j.$$

If $X_i$'s are completely dependent, then it trivially holds. Can we generalize it to just saying they are identical (irrespective of whether or not they are independent)?

Comment: do you want this to hold for any measurable $f$ or are there restrictions on what $f$ can be?

Comment: $f$ is continuous.

Comment: You are wrong when you claim "If the $X_i$'s are completely dependent, then it is trivially true." since, for example, if $f$ is the identity function and $X_j = aX_i+b$ (completely dependent random variables), then $E[X_i]\neq E[X_j] = aE[X_i]+b$ except in the triival case when $(a,b)=(1,0)$,  What _is_ trivially true is that if $X_i$ and $X_j$ have the same _marginal_ distribution, then $E[f(X_i)]=E[f(X_j)]$. Independence or dependence is irrelevant in this case.

Comment: It would hold under exchangeability.